Is there an all in one solution to run a lightning node and bitcoin node on a single device and then access it via API?
I want to add lightning payments to my app service. For this I want to create an external server that can process lightning payments on behalf of my app.
Basically, I would like the app to send commands like send_lightning_to, register_webhook_on_payment and dump_to_cold_wallet without having the server running my software hold the necessary keys.
I was looking at umbrel and there was some mention of an API, but it's not documented anywhere. So what are my options if I want an all-in-one node solution that can be controlled by an API, preferably with some kind of authentication built in?
